# WordPress plus jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, dashboard

How do you add javascript/jQuery function to work with WordPress plugins.

For example, I want to call a jquery function on submit or button click. Or for client-side form validation.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are a lot of methods to do that:

1. Write your plugin, hooking wp_enqueue_scripts action, including external .js file with your jsvascript code
2. The same, but hooking wp_enqueue_scripts from whithin your theme
3. Include your external javascript file using < script> tag inside head.php (or other) of your theme
4. Include your code inline into < script> tag inside any of your theme's file.

Comment: Where should I put my .js file?

Comment: 1. In the same folder of your plugin (and use plugin_dir_url(__ FILE __); to obtain URL of this dir)


2. In your theme folder (and use get_template_directory_uri() to obtain URL of your theme dir)

Answer (score 0):

I believe this page could help you : http://matthewruddy.com/using-jquery-with-wordpress/

> Probably the most common mistake developers make is loading jQuery by
>   printing the “” tag into the header. Never do this! If you do,
>   any plugin/theme that requires jQuery will be broken as a result of
>   your mess. This is because jQuery will be loaded twice, which will
>   throw errors and break stuff. Instead, use the PHP code below.

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_script', 'load_jquery' );
function load_jquery() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
}
```

Comment: Where should I write my scripts? Should I make an external .js file or just write it inside my plugin?